# sending parameters without using hidden parameters through jquery

Tags: jquery

I am making a such kind of application that when i click on a button it should send number of parameters and these parameters should be used after 3rd or 4th submit().So those parameters are maintained in each form.I want to send all those parameters without declaring hidden parameters using JQuery.How can i perform this operation.Some other alternatives are also welcomed.

Comment: Without knowing your particulars, this is a case when I'd use hidden fields. What is the reason for not wanting hidden parameters?

Comment: Sharing a more concrete code example of what you're trying to accomplish will help us provide an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cookies,indexeddb(support major modern browsers) or websql(deprecated)

Comment: @jasen-it's increasing the no. of parameters with each request.I want a technique that creates parameters associated with request temporarily.
suppose::::
<input type="hidden" name="id"/>
:
:
:
:

Comment: @jasen-it's increasing the no. of parameters with each request.I want a technique that creates parameters associated with request temporarily.
suppose::::
<input type="hidden" name="id"/>
:
:
:
:
upto 20 hidden params.

so I want a way that lets me send params in such way that I can send some of these params in javascript function before submit a form using jquery.